# java.exe code error in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using xamarin android for my application. When i add the following code to my axml file it shows the error like "java.exe exited with code 2"

```
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/bordertop"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
          android:layout_marginBottom="71dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="5">
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/sportscar"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imageView1"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
              android:layout_weight="0.5" />
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/seatbelt"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imageView4"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/money"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imageView5"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/customer"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imageView3"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/groupbutton"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/imageView2"
              android:layout_weight="1.5" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="5">
          <TextView
             android:text="Four"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/txtdtl1"
             android:textColor="#13317E"
             android:layout_weight="1.2"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
          <TextView
              android:text="4"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtdtl2"
              android:textColor="#13317E"
              android:layout_weight="0.5" />
          <TextView
              android:text="PayTm"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtdtl3"
              android:textColor="#13317E"
              android:layout_weight="1.3" />
          <TextView
              android:text="3.5"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtdtl4"
              android:textColor="#13317E"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <TextView
              android:text="CUG,FB,GP-VP"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtdtl5"
              android:textColor="#13317E"
              android:drawableTop="@color/BLUE"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post the log...

Comment: 3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2072,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Perhaps you miss `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: i have already added this on top of axml file. The above codes, i have inserted inbetween the parent linear layout.

Comment: i have 50+ icon images in my drawable folder. When i add new image to drawable folder, it also show the same above error.

Comment: Can anybody please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did it pointed to any lines ?

Comment: No, it is not pointed to any line. It just show like "java.exe exited with code 2". When i go to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets‌", it contains the following line "  <CompileToDalvik "

Comment: hi john joe,
Finally I got the solution. I have updated my xamarin in visual studio to 4.6.0.279 and it works fine now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Congratulations.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after a longtime. I have updated my xamarin in visual studio to 4.6.0.279 and it works fine now.